# Onblur event fires before another div's onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onblur

[image]

As above, I have  a button that, when clicked, will open the sub-menu. For each option in the sub-menu there are three elements (there's actually more I think, but will keep it as 3 for simplicity). I give focus to the main div (white 'frame') of the sub-menu. Onblur of this div - I then hide the sub-menu.

This all behaves as expected - but I have the probem that when one of the 3 elements for a particular option are clicked (i.e. given focus), the main div will close due to it's onblur event handler - and the PopUp function that's linked to the onClick event of the elements for the options in the sub-menu are not fired/reached.

I need someway of only handling the onblur event of the main div in this way if the options haven't been clicked.

I have JQuery to use obviously so I'm more than happy to work with that to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to post this answer - in the hope that someone can improve on it or suggest an alternative because it really does feel like a work around.

But, what I've done is on the onblur event - instead of instantly hiding the div, I've put in a small delay using a timeout so I don't alter the precedence of the onblur/onclick events fired but in effect give the onclick 'a chance' to fire.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. I don't think it feels kludgy, I think it's a good way to change an event's precedence without knowing anything about the other events.

Comment: Using this, I've noticed onblur will still always occur before onclick with a delay below 45ms, and sometimes when the delay is 46-50ms. Not sure what causes the variable result, but it can go either way on the same PC/browser. I'm guessing the range could spread or be completely different for others, so I've set the timer to 250ms just to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following idea: 
(Not tested so it will need some tuning/debugging..)

```
function mouseOverSubMenu(mouseX, mouseY) {
    var divTop = $('.sub_menu').offset().top;
    var divLeft = $('.sub_menu').offset().left;
    var divRight = divLeft + $('.sub_menu').width();
    var divBottom = divTop + $('.sub_menu').height();


    return (mouseX >= divLeft && 
            mouseX < divRight &&
              mouseY >= divTop &&
              mouseY < divBottom);
}


$('.sub_menu, .other_elements').hover(
    function(e) {
        if (mouseOverStartButton(e.pageX, e.pageY)) {
            // show menu
        }
    },
    function(e) {
        if (!mouseOverStartButton(e.pageX, e.pageY)) {  
            //hide menu
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I think this may be the solution, definitely an improvement on mine.