# Wait for document mousedown to complete before element onclick can start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel that slides open on an element click called "details" and populates the panel via ajax depending on the data attribute value. I also have it setup that if you close outside that panel, it will close. If the panel is open and the user clicks on a different "details" element, I want the panel to close and open again populated with the data from the new data attribute.

Problem is that the codes checks if the panel is visible and won't load the ajax if it is. How can I change this so  the `click` event knows the `mousedown` event is completed before it does it's thing?

```
// SLIDING PANEL
$(".details").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var panel = $("#DetailsPanel");
    var mkey = $(this).data("masterkey-id");
    var _self = $(this);
        // fetch data ONLY when panel is hidden...
        // otherwise it fetches data when the panel is closing
        if (!panel.is(':visible')) {
            panel.load("/com/franchise/leads.cfc?method=getLeadDetails", { mkey: mkey }, function(response, status, xhr) {
                // if the ajax source wasn't loaded properly
                if (status !== "success") {
                    var msg = "<p>Sorry, but there was an error loading the document.</p>";
                    panel.html(msg);
                };
                // this is part of the .load() callback so it fills the panel BEFORE opening it
                panel.toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, "fast", function(){
                    _self.parent().parent().addClass("warning");
                });
            });
        } else {
            panel.toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, "fast", function(){
                _self.parent().parent().removeClass("warning");
            });
        };

    return false;
});

$(document).on("mousedown", function(){
    $("#DetailsPanel").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, "fast", function(){
        //_self.parent().parent().removeClass("warning");
    });
});
// don't close panel when clicking inside it
$(document).on("mousedown","#DetailsPanel",function(e){e.stopPropagation();});

$(document).on("click", "#ClosePanel", function(){
    $("#DetailsPanel").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, "fast", function(){
        $("#LeadsTable tr").removeClass("warning");
    });
});
// END SLIDING PANEL
```

Comment: I believe you can ask jQuery if the element is currently animating, and treat it as hidden if so.  jQuery API website seems really iffy for me today though (caching problems), so can't find the specifics...

Comment: Yes api.jquery.com is totally fubar today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found this little nugget http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/09/jquery-waiting-for-multiple-animations-to-complete/ and it works pretty good. No issues so far.

Here is the new code

```
    $(".details").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var panel = $("#DetailsPanel");
        var mkey = $(this).data("masterkey-id");
        var _self = $(this);
            // fetch data ONLY when panel is hidden...
            // otherwise it fetches data when the panel is closing
        var wait = setInterval(function() {
            if( !$("#DetailsPanel").is(":animated") ) {
                clearInterval(wait);
                // This piece of code will be executed
                // after DetailsPanel is complete.
                if (!panel.is(':visible')) {
                    panel.load("/com/franchise/leads.cfc?method=getLeadDetails", { mkey: mkey }, function(response, status, xhr) {
                        // if the ajax source wasn't loaded properly
                        if (status !== "success") {
                            var msg = "<p>Sorry, but there was an error loading the document.</p>";
                            panel.html(msg);
                        };
                        // this is part of the .load() callback so it fills the panel BEFORE opening it
                        panel.toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, "fast", function(){
                            _self.parent().parent().addClass("warning");
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    panel.toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, "fast", function(){
                        _self.parent().parent().removeClass("warning");
                    });
                };
            }
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a timeout worked for me in another context:

```
onclick="window.setTimeout( function(){ DO YOUR STUFF }, 2);"
```

This solves many problems of this type.

Comment: It seems unfortunate, because it feels a bit hacky, but this is the only solution I've got working in the past too. Interested to see if there are any alternatives. +1. I suppose it's sort of related to this problem I had a while back? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755625/onblur-event-fires-before-another-divs-onclick

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about this but if you use "mouseup" instead "click" could work as you expect. Try it and let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: I did try that, just happens all too fast.

Comment: Just for curiosity, are you tried e.stopImmediatePropagation()? I remember I used this in the past for something like this.

Comment: Won't that completely stop the click event from happening?